# How to solve a matrix $ Ax=0 $, where matrix $ A $ is a function of $ ω^2 $

Tags: differential-equations, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

I have a matrix $ A $ which depends on $ ω^2 $. I wanted to solve for $ ω $. The usual procedure is taking the `Det[A]` and equate to zero and solve for it. How can I use a built-in function in *Mathematica* to solve for eigenvalues? I tried with `Eigenvalues` and `Eigensystem` but they won't work since $ ω $ is sitting inside the $ A $ matrix.

Comment: What's wrong with NSolve[Det[A] == 0, \[Omega]] or just Solve ?

Answer (score 1):

Find the characteristic polynomial (which is a polynomial whose roots are the eigenvalues), and then set the eigenvalue to 0. Then setting the polynomial to 0 will give an equation for ω^2. For example:

```
A = {{ω^2+1, -ω^2}, {ω^4-ω^2+1, 1}};

poly = CharacteristicPolynomial[A, λ] /. λ -> 0;

Solve[poly == 0, ω, Cubics->False] //RootReduce
```

> {{ω -> Root[1 + 2 #1^2 - #1^4 + #1^6 &, 3]}, {ω -> 
>      Root[1 + 2 #1^2 - #1^4 + #1^6 &, 4]}, {ω -> 
>      Root[1 + 2 #1^2 - #1^4 + #1^6 &, 2]}, {ω -> 
>      Root[1 + 2 #1^2 - #1^4 + #1^6 &, 5]}, {ω -> 
>      Root[1 + 2 #1^2 - #1^4 + #1^6 &, 1]}, {ω -> 
>      Root[1 + 2 #1^2 - #1^4 + #1^6 &, 6]}}

Comment: only works for small matrices. I have large  system say 12 cross 12

Comment: @vijay Then you should provide an example.